# How can I add a logout button to my logout page which has security features?

Tags: php, html

When the user goes to my [website](http://webbrowserinfo.96.lt/logindone/logincode/V1/) after the user logins in on this [page](http://webbrowserinfo.96.lt/logindone/logincode/V1/) they're then presented with this [page](http://webbrowserinfo.96.lt/logindone/logincode/V1/homepage.php) . However, if I type in the full URL webbrowserinfo.96.lt/logindone/logincode/V1/homepage.php it loads regardless if the user logins in or not. From doing my own tests it has something to do with the log out button.

Therefore, I was thinking I need to do something like this below. However, when I add this code to my protected password page i.e `homepage.php` it doesn't work i.e nothing happens when I click logout.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
           <!-- Logout button -->
           <div class="inner_container">
               <button class="logout_button" type="submit">Log Out<i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
               </button>
            </div>
</form>
```

Here is my full code for the password protected code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
      <!-- Site title, CSS external file and font awesome -->
      <title>Login Page - Created by Liam Docherty</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body class="bg-white">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="py-5 text-center">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
            <h2>Checkout form</h2>
            <p class="lead">Below is an example form built entirely with Bootstrap's form controls. Each required form group has a validation state that can be triggered by attempting to submit the form without completing it.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
               <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                  <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
               </h4>
               <ul class="list-group mb-3">
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                     <div>
                        <h6 class="my-0">Product name</h6>
                        <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-muted">$12</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                     <div>
                        <h6 class="my-0">Second product</h6>
                        <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-muted">$8</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                     <div>
                        <h6 class="my-0">Third item</h6>
                        <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-muted">$5</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
                     <div class="text-success">
                        <h6 class="my-0">Promo code</h6>
                        <small>EXAMPLECODE</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-success">-$5</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                     <span>Total (USD)</span>
                     <strong>$20</strong>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <form class="card p-2">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Promo code">
                     <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Redeem</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
               <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
               <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           Valid first name is required.
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           Valid last name is required.
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="username">Username</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                           <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                           Your username is required.
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="email">Email <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
                     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="address">Address</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="34 Hoxton liam street" required>
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please enter your shipping address.
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
               <!-- Logout button -->
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php" role="button">Signout button</a>
               </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[My website has three scripts here they're if you need to see them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7MVT.png)

BELOW IS THE LOGIN PAGE CODE

```
<?php
   //PHP method to use cache memory to store details
   session_start();
   //Makes the "config.php" file available to be executed from this page
   require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- Site title, CSS external file and font awesome -->
      <title>Login Page - Created by Liam Docherty</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="main-wrapper">
         <center>
            <h2>Login Form - Created by Liam Docherty</h2>
         </center>
         <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img src="imgs/icon-person-512.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
         </div>
         <!-- THE FORM -->
         <!-- action="index.php" -- This attribute shows where the PHP script that does the processing is located -->
         <!-- method="post" -- The attribute identifies the action that will be performed with the data of the form. I.E. POST data to the "users" database -->
         <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <div class="inner_container">
               <label><b>Username</b></label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
               <label><b>Password</b></label>
               <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
               <!-- The Login button -->
               <button class="login_button" name="login" type="submit">Login</button>
               <!-- The button that is linked to the "register.php" page -->
               <a href="register.php"><button type="button" class="register_btn">Register</button></a>
            </div>
         </form>
         <?php
            //Condition, checking the Login button is pressed
            if(isset($_POST['login']))
            {
                //The data from the Form (username & password) is stored into the @$username & @$passwordVariables
                //You use @ before a VARIABLE in PHP when you do not want to initialise the VARIABLE before using it
                @$username=$_POST['username'];
                @$password=$_POST['password'];

                //Statement that will SELECT the data from the "login" table, WHERE the Usename and Password typed match the typed ones
                //Once the database is checked, if login details match than it stores the data in the "$query" VARIABLE
                $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' ";
                //echo $query;

                //This statement performs both the connection to the database using the values in the "$con" VARIABLE and
                //The SELECT statement stored in the "$query" VARIABLE
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);

                //IF the "$query_run" is run successfully, then
                if($query_run)
                {
                    //Check if the Username and Password exist in the database, if they exist
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                    {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                    //Sent the user to the "homepage.php" page
                    header( "Location: homepage.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //IF NOT, Display the message below
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("No such User exists. Invalid Credentials")</script>';
                    }
                }

                //IF the "$query_run" is NOT successful, then
                else
                {
                    //Display this message
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Database Error")</script>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
            ?>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

> MY OWN UPDATED ATTEMPT BASED ON HELP

This issue with the code below is that it doesn't let me actually login. This is good though as it stops a user just typing in the full file path of the URL and bypassing the login system.

```
<?php
//check if session id is set. If it is not set, user will be redirected back to login page

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     header('Location:index.php');
     die();
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
      <!-- Site title, CSS external file and font awesome -->
      <title>Login Page - Created by Liam Docherty</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body class="bg-white">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="py-5 text-center">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
            <h2>Checkout form</h2>
            <p class="lead">Below is an example form built entirely with Bootstrap's form controls. Each required form group has a validation state that can be triggered by attempting to submit the form without completing it.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
               <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                  <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
               </h4>
               <ul class="list-group mb-3">
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                     <div>
                        <h6 class="my-0">Product name</h6>
                        <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-muted">$12</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                     <div>
                        <h6 class="my-0">Second product</h6>
                        <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-muted">$8</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                     <div>
                        <h6 class="my-0">Third item</h6>
                        <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-muted">$5</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
                     <div class="text-success">
                        <h6 class="my-0">Promo code</h6>
                        <small>EXAMPLECODE</small>
                     </div>
                     <span class="text-success">-$5</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                     <span>Total (USD)</span>
                     <strong>$20</strong>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <form class="card p-2">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Promo code">
                     <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Redeem</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
               <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
               <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           Valid first name is required.
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           Valid last name is required.
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="username">Username</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                           <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                           Your username is required.
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="email">Email <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
                     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="address">Address</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="34 Hoxton liam street" required>
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please enter your shipping address.
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
               <!-- Logout button -->
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php" role="button">Signout button</a>
               </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_this will allow the user just to write the full file path for the URL link and be able to access the protected webpage_" Your "protected" page won't check username/password? I'm not sure how exactly the page is "protected" if you can get there just by navigating to the page directly.

Comment: That's what I'm saying and that's what i'm trying to fix.

Comment: So your question is how to check the username/password is correct when the form is submitted?

Comment: No, after the user logins in on this page http://webbrowserinfo.96.lt/logindone/logincode/V1/index.php they're then presented with this page http://webbrowserinfo.96.lt/logindone/logincode/V1/homepage.php. However, if I type in the full URL http://webbrowserinfo.96.lt/logindone/logincode/V1/homepage.php it loads regardless if the user logins in or not. From doing my own tests it has something to do with the log out button.

Comment: Sorry for the post being confusing, I will change it now to try make it more clear.

Comment: You need to read about the session:https://www.phparch.com/2018/01/php-sessions-in-depth/

Comment: You will need php code on your homepage.php to check if the session variables (e.g $_SESSION['username'] and $_SESSION['password']) are set and if they are NOT set then do a redirect to the login page. If they are set that means the user has logged in. (This is a very basic way of doing it. You will need to make it more secure.)

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the URL and the suggestion.

Comment: I followed this tutorial before to create a secure login in php. It might be useful for you :) https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: Strange that nobody talks about the glaring SQL-Injection vulnerability! I just was able to log into your site without even knowing any credentials! **Don't** build a login system on your own before you know enough about security/parametrized SQL querys/etc. Especially if that page is open to the web. Somebody can do whatever he wants with your database right now!

Comment: @Lucas Hi, I'm aware of what you're talking about. However, this is just a test for an assignment. I'm still at a basic level with this aspect of web development. :)

Comment: @Liam Hi Liam i've added an answer. I hope its more clear than what I was trying to say in the comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a very simple solution for your logout functionality for the purpose of a school/college assignment.

A "live" production website will need a lot of security in the login system (but that is a whole other topic).
I can see you know this already so i'll continue with my solution ;)

Firstly the logout form you did was a great idea well done. But I think it didn't work because I've noticed you haven't closed the `<form>` tag for your "Billing address" form within your homepage.php so you should do that before anything else.

Here's my advice on the full structure. Hope it helps :)

## homepage.php

1. Add php to the top of the homepage above the `<!doctype html>` to check if the username is set and if not redirect to the index/login page.
2. Add an HTML form to the homepage with a "sign out" submit button which will redirect to the login/index page when submitted.
   (Make sure you put this form outside any other forms.)
3. Add a javaScript function called confirmLogOut to the homepage which will prompt the user to confirm they wish to log out.

So you should add the following code to your homepage.php (fit it in to your code where i've demonstarted-hopefully it's clear)

```
<?php
  //start the session
  session_start();
  //If the user is not logged in, send them to the index/login page
  if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit();
  }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
//javaScript function for prompting user to confirm they want to log out.
//This will be executed when the signout button is pressed.
function confirmLogOut(){
  var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to log out?");
  if(confirmation){
    //the user has confirmed they would like to log out so we submit the form
    //ie return true
    return true;
  }else{
    //the user has canceled their log out request so we don't submit the form
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Log out/sign out button form-->
  <!--When the following form is submitted we called the confirmLogOut javaScript function in order to prompt the 
user to confirm they wish to log out before redirecting to the index/login page-->
  <form id="form-log-out" method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="return confirmLogOut()">
      <input name="log_out" type="hidden" value="1"/>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Signout button" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## index.php

This is the full php code which should be at the top of your login/index page

```
<?php
  //PHP method to use cache memory to store details
  session_start();
  //Makes the "config.php" file available to be executed from this page
  require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
  if(isset($_POST["log_out"]) && ($_POST["log_out"] == '1')) {
    //the log_out post variable is set and is equal to 1. 
    //This means we have come from another page after pressing the log out button.          
    //unset all session values
    $_SESSION = array();

    //Destroy the session 
    session_destroy();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am not explaining very well. First, you need to set a session id for the users and create a if statement to check if they are set for pages that you do not want to reveal for unauthorized users.

e.g

```
//check if session id is set. If it is not set, user will be redirected back to login page

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     header('Location:index.php');
     die();
}
else
// send authorized users to homepage.
{
     header('Location:homepage.php');

}
```

You have to kill sessions as well after logging out and you can do it by the following:

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
// kill session    
session_destroy();

// send user back to login page.
header("Location: index.php");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You wont need the else part of that as they will already be on the homepage so no need to redirect. Otherwise this looks good

Comment: Hi, thanks from doing my research from what Sarah suggested this looks spot on and fantastic. Do you mind showing me to where add it as I just added it to my code. However, I cannot seem to get the code to correctly work still.

Comment: @suppko just noticed an error in the code. There shouldn't be a colon in front of location. It should just be: header('Location: index.php');

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e13ea198961795e7600e708ef8822e20c8a90b92 @suppko Here is what I tried

Comment: @Sarah like this "Location: 'index.php' ?

Comment: You need to add this to the top of your homepage: <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     header('Location: index.php');
     exit();
} ?>   (Note: replace index.php with the name of your loginpage.)

Comment: You should only kill the session in the logOut function. (From the link you've sent it looks like you've added the unset($_SESSION['username']); and session_destroy() code to your login code, instead of logout code)

Comment: If im not wrong that is your login method, so why are you killing your session variable right after you validate the user and pass. You do not need to validate any sessions as your else statement already deny unauthorised users from logging in. What you need to do is to validate the sessions on any page that you do not want unauthorised users to see.

Comment: This is getting very confusing :( haha only my second week learning all this. I'll do that now. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Create a logout.php that destroys the session and tag it to your logout button. That should work.

Comment: ahh I just messed up my website. Nothing to do with you lot, just being all new to this.

Comment: @Liam haha no probs Liam. It is confusing sometimes over texting. I recommend following that "secure login" tutorial link I sent. That's how I created my login before.

Comment: @Liam aw no. Hope you get it fixed :)

Comment: You may also want to learn more about using prepared statements as your codes are susceptible to SQL injections. The link Sarah provided helps with that. Good luck!